# Issue with strings and dictionaries in python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I'm using the click package to get input for one or more variables which get loaded in as a combined dictionary.  Each entry is then joined and the combined string is added to the end of a base URL and sent through the requests package to receive some xml data.

Earlier I had an issue with one of the variables that let you search through a range, such as

```
[value1, value2]
```

Python added double quotes around it so the search function didn't operate correctly, so I used

```
.replace('"', '')
```

on the joined string before combined with the base url and that seemed to fix that problem.  The issue now is that individual input that contains more than one word now doesn't produce the same output as the actual search engine online.  I have to use quotes when I input the information to keep it as a single argument, but then the quotes get removed by the function above and I believe that is what is causing the issue.

I think if I have a way to access individual entries of this dictionary and remove the double quotes from only certain entries then that should get the job done.  But if I am overlooking something please let me know.

Help is appreciated.

Code added below:

```
import click
import requests

@click.command()
@click.option(--variable1)
@click.option(--variable2)

query_list=[variable1, variable2]


query=''.join(query_list)

base_url = "abc.com...."

response=requests.get(base_url,query)
```

Comment: Can you add example input and some more code. Thanks.

Comment: marxmacher, added code on OP.    Input example could be "[10000,100000]" and "I am confused".  Since they are part of a data dictionary, they would output as...  variable1:"[10000,100000]" and variable2:"I am confused"